# Replacing a space and some other character in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Why does this code not work?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "You need the new version for this. Please update app ...";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(". ", ".\\\\n").replaceAll(" ...", "..."));
}
```

This is my wanted output:

> You need the new version for this.\nPlease update app...

Thanks for the information

Comment: And what is your actual output?

Comment: Do you want your output to be split into 2 lines? Was \n intended to be a new line char?

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev If he did I assume he would have posted the output on two separate lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.replaceAll` method takes Regex as first argument.

So you need to escape your *dot* (`.`), as it has special meaning in Regex, which matches any character.

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\. ", ".\\\\n").replaceAll(" \\.\\.\\.", "..."));
```

However, for your given input, you can simply use `String.replace` method, as it does not take `Regex`, and has an added advantage of that.

Comment: Using `replaceAll` here is overkill imo - you might want to mention this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a special regex character and will match anything. You need to escape it like this: `\\.`

So to match three dots you must use following regex: `"\\.\\.\\."`

what you want is

```
s.replaceAll("\\. ", ".\n").replaceAll(" \\.\\.\\.", "...")
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `replaceAll` - use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead. `replaceAll` takes a regular expression when it is not needed here (and hence it will be unnecessarily inefficient).

```
String s = "You need the new version for this. Please update app ...";
System.out.println(s.replace(". ", ".\\n").replace(" ...", "..."));
```

(Also note that I've replaced `".\\\\n"` with `".\\n"` here, which produces the desired output.)

Comment: your version produces "You need the new version for this.\\nPlease update app..."

Comment: it still wrong: You need the new version for this.\nPlease update app...  \n is not LF its '\' + 'n'

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev The OP doesn't want a new line character - he actually wants "\n" in the text (which is produced here). `s.replace(". ", ".\\n").replace(" ...", "...").equals("You need the new version for this.\\nPlease update app...") == true`.

Answer (score 0):

try as

```
    System.out.println(s.replace(". ", ".\n").replace(" ...", "..."));
```

this gives

```
You need the new version for this.
Please update app...
```